# wp_query by last month + sort posts

Tags: query-posts, sort

I'm using the WordPress plugin 'I recommend this', it allows people to 'like' posts. The value is stored as a meta key, which we can query to generate a 'most recommended' page.

Plugin -> http://wordpress.org/support/plugin/i-recommend-this

The loop.

```
<?php 
        query_posts('&orderby=meta_value&meta_key=_recommended');
        if (have_posts()): while (have_posts()) : the_post();
    ?>
        <article <?php post_class('item-post block'); ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">


         <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
        </article>


    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

This works, it finds the most recommended posts.

Two questions.

1. How do I limit the posts returned to a date range of say, the last 3 months?
2. In a similar vein, how could I then have a button for 'Most popular this week' that'd allow users to see a filtered result of posts from the last 7 days?

Answer (score 0):

The recent addition of date query makes it possible to use very elaborate conditions, see [Date Parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Date_Parameters) documentation in Codex.

As for outputting certain set of posts the simplest way might be to create dedicated page with [custom page template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates) for it.